# Cannot create a model object in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I create an model class in rails and test both ok in local development and production environment. 
However, I deployed the rails app to AWS and find super strange problem. 
I cannot use my model anymore.

For example,

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.6)
Mgmt_Server :001 > defined?(Game)
=> "constant" 
Mgmt_Server :002 > Game.create
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ... etc
```

in development of AWS

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
Mgmt_Server :004 > Game.create!
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `games` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES   ('2015-05-21 08:41:16', '2015-05-21 08:41:16')
(2.0ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Game id: 2, name: nil, description: nil, platform: nil, state: nil, exe: nil, launch_command: nil, terminate_command: nil, waiting_queue_size: nil, allow_play: false, created_at: "2015-05-21 08:41:16", updated_at: "2015-05-21 08:41:16">
```

Totally no idea about the root cause... 
Im pretty sure no problem in db site beacuase I used same db for testing.

game.rb

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_defaults
  has_many :game_save
end
```

backtrace

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-21:~/MgmtService/Mgmt_Server/config$ rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.6)
Mgmt_Server :001 > Game
 => Game (call 'Game.connection' to establish a connection) 
Mgmt_Server :002 > Game.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
Mgmt_Server :003 > Game.create
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/beefcake-1.0.0/lib/beefcake.rb:229:in `block in initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/beefcake-1.0.0/lib/beefcake.rb:228:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/beefcake-1.0.0/lib/beefcake.rb:228:in `initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
... 1 levels...
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

TKS

(note)

After I make some change in game.rb =>

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_defaults
  #has_many :game_save   (remove this line)
end
```

I can successfully create a model in production env.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-21:~/MgmtService/Mgmt_Server/app/models$ rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.6)
Mgmt_Server :001 > Game.create
 => #<Game id: 1, name: nil, description: nil, platform: nil, state: nil, exe: nil, launch_command: nil, terminate_command: nil, waiting_queue_size: nil, allow_play: false, created_at: "2015-05-21 10:05:42", updated_at: "2015-05-21 10:05:42">
```

TKS.

Comment: What's the backtrace?

Comment: Have you run migrations there?

Comment: Sure, I drop and migrate over times.

Comment: Could you past 1. backtrace and 2. Game class code? Point 1 is quite crucial.

Comment: Are you sure you ran a command something on the lines of - rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Yes, I run RAILS_ENV=production ... etc for production env. 
I just doubt if any possible for rails not loading game.rb in production env?

Comment: Thanks for help. I added model file  and backtrace to original post.

Comment: What's beefcake?  That's what's erroring.  Have a look at the line in beefcake that's causing the problem.

Comment: @MaxWilliams it's ruby implementation of Google protocol buffers (it seems Google have just invented Foxpro dbf format :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the same with `DISABLE_SPRING=1` environment variable defined, it seems it calls AR, which in turn calls beefcake, which can not initialize without header data for the subsequent serialized game_save objects.

If it will help redeploy with `--without development test`.